# Append a slice from a map value does not affect the map

Tags: go

```
mp := map[int][]int{}
slice := make([]int, 0, 1)
fmt.Printf("slice address:%p\n", slice)
mp[0] = slice
slice = append(slice, 1)
fmt.Println("after append")
fmt.Printf("slice address:%p\n", slice)
fmt.Println("slice:", slice)
fmt.Println("mp[0]:", mp[0])
fmt.Printf("mp[0] address:%p\n", mp[0])
```

output:

```
slice address:0xc042008f78  
after append  
slice address:0xc042008f78  
slice: [1]  
mp[0]: []  
mp[0] address:0xc042008f78
```

The address of the slice does not change as its cap is large enough during append. So why the map value does not take effect?

Answer (score 4):

As explained in [Go Slices: usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals#TOC_4.), two slices may point to the same memory location, but may have different `len` and `cap` attributes.

Answer (score 3):

In Golang it is mentioned in blog on [Go Slices: usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)

> Slicing does not copy the slice's data. It creates a new slice value
>   that points to the original array. This makes slice operations as
>   efficient as manipulating array indices. Therefore, modifying the
>   elements (not the slice itself) of a re-slice modifies the elements of
>   the original slice:

```
slice = append(slice, 1)
```

So in the above case it is creating a new slice with pointing to the same original underlying array. That is the reason it is showing the same address.

To get the data of underlying array pointed by slice use `reflect` with `unsafe`:

```
hdr := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&slice))
data := *(*[1]int)(unsafe.Pointer(hdr.Data))
```

Working code on [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/meGuaiNEMSb)

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the fact, that multiple slices can be backed by the same data but use different "sections" of the data. This means, that yes, an element is added to the data backing `mp[0]`, but the length of the slice in `mp` is not changed. You can do that manually:

```
fmt.Println(mp[0][:1])
```

which does print `[1]`.

You can grow any slice to it's capacity without changing the underlying data by using `slice[:cap(slice)]`. `slice[:n]` will panic if `cap(slice) < n`.
`slice[n]` on the other hand will panic when `len(slice) <= n`. I assume that the former is possible to allow the growing of slices without changing the underlying data (as far as that is possible). The latter, I would say, is "normal" behavior.

This also explains why `mp[0][:2]` panics, as `cap(mp[0])` is `1`.

For more details you might want to read [this official blog post](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals), as suggested by Flimzy.

Comment: Can you explain why `[:1]` prints the data, where `[0]` panics ?

Comment: I mean, mp[0][0] panics, and this is expected, its len is equal to 0. But its unclear why `mp[0][:1]` worked, where `mp[0][:2]` panics as expected.

Comment: @mh-cbon I see how that can appear un-intuitive. I have updated my answer, to include the relevant rules for slicing and accessing and my guess as to why these rules are this way.